# Unable to eliminate a string of characters from a String using "Strip" in Python

Tags: python

I have used the following method to delete a certain trailing string of characters 'lbs' from a string of characters. But, when I run my code and print out the result nothing is changed and the string of characters hasn't been eliminated. Would appreciate your help in this situation! Thanks for the help!

```
Data:
**Weights:**
0        159lbs
1        183lbs
2        150lbs
3        168lbs
4        154lbs

**Code:**
# Converting the Weights to an Integer Value from a String
for x in Weights:
    if (type(x) == str):
        x.strip('lbs')

**Output:**    
Weights:
0        159lbs
1        183lbs
2        150lbs
3        168lbs
4        154lbs
```

Comment: `x.strip('lbs')` generated a new string, with the indicated letters removed from the ends.  However, this accomplished absolutely nothing, as you didn't do anything with the new string.

Comment: @jasonharper Thanks for the help! I assigned x = x.strip('lbs') but, nothing changed in the Weights!

Comment: @Pressing_Keys_24_7 check my answer. It changes the values in weights. You can't change a list value just by iterating over it. You need to specify the index.

Comment: @ahmadjanan I see. Thanks for the help:)

Comment: @ahmadjanan I am trying to figure some other way as well! Given an upvote:)

Comment: @Pressing_Keys_24_7 I added a second approach as well to my answer, if that is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are stripping the value from the string but not saving it in the list.
Try using numeric indexing as follows:

```
Weights = ['159lbs', '183lbs', '150lbs', '168lbs', '154lbs']

# Converting the Weights to an Integer Value from a String
for x in range(len(Weights)):
    if (type(Weights[x]) == str):
        Weights[x] = Weights[x].strip('lbs')
```

However, if you aren't comfortable with using a ranged loop, you can enumerate instead as follows:

```
Weights = ['159lbs', '183lbs', '150lbs', '168lbs', '154lbs']

# Converting the Weights to an Integer Value from a String
for i, x in enumerate(Weights):
    if (type(x) == str):
        Weights[i] = x.strip('lbs')
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this helpful to you..?

Here I haven't used `isinstance(line, str)` to explicitly check the line whether it is a `string` or not as the line number is an `integer` (I suppose).

```
with open('Data.txt', 'r') as dataFile:
    dataFile.readline()
    for line in dataFile.readlines():
        number, value = line.strip().split()
        print(value.strip('lbs'))

159
183
150
168
154
```

Here I have put data into a txt file as;

```
**Weights:**
0        159lbs
1        183lbs
2        150lbs
3        168lbs
4        154lbs
```